# Is there a Database Dictionary feature in MySQL Workbench?

Tags: mysql, dictionary, mysql-workbench

I have developed my ERD, which is great feature in MySQL Workbench, but what I am wondering is there a feature on the Mac version that will export a Database Dictionary? In a table or Excel format, which outlines all the tables the columns and the column table with any of the comments that have also been inputted?

Currently I am writing them out by hand - and would be great if there was a time saving way of doing this.

Answer (score 0):

There **is** such a feature, called DbDoc, but it's only available in the commercial edition of MySQL Workbench available with a MySQL subscription.